# String object creation in loop

Tags: java, string, object

How many objects will be created by the following code?

```
for(int i = 0; i< = 1000 ; i++)
{
    String s = new String("Hello");
}
```

And will throw an OutOfMemory exception or not?

Comment: Everyone should try it out first, but I would like someone to explain how to calculate the number of objects created, as the user seems a beginner

Comment: It shouldn't throw any errors. The variable s is local to the scope of the for loop so the GC will delete it as soon as it needs space.

Comment: Do we also consider object created in String pool for "Hello"? so the count should be 1001

Comment: @sidgate Thanks, i need someone to explain how to check number of objects created.

Comment: It will create 1001 objects, but at the end of the for loop there will only be 1 object left in the string pool (plus various `String` instances waiting to be garbage collected (with no references to them)).

Comment: One object for "Hello" and other 1000 for each for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to loop 1001 times, thus creating 1001 independent `String`-objects. `s` is a local variable inside the loop, thus the garbage collector is going to free the memory occupied by these no longer referenced instances as soon as the system needs the memory. Thus, I would not expect any memory issues.

As stated by Trengot there will also be one additional object created for the `String`-pool. If you consider that it will total to a *creation* of 1002 `String`-objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the above case 1000 object will be created, string pooling will not  work. 
On regarding the `OutOfMemory` error it depend on the memory configuration.
When you create string as below only one object will be created.

```
for(int i = 0; i< = 1000 ; i++){
     String s = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: The code is looping 1001 times (see condition in for-loop), thus 1001 objects will be created :-) However, your second point is valid, thus +1!